# Curl and Laravel, always redirects

Tags: laravel, curl, cookies, laravel-5, python-requests

I am trying to do a simple simple curl to a Laravel (5.2) app running on my machine:

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1" http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt
```

With this result:

**The request header**:

```
*   Trying 192.168.1.65...
* Connected to 192.168.1.65 (192.168.1.65) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /pt HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.65:8000
> Accept: */*
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
```

**The response header and body**:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Host: 192.168.1.65:8000
< Connection: close
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
< Set-Cookie: lang=pt; expires=Fri, 04-Nov-2016 08:53:50 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Location: http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 08:53:50 GMT
< Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjNReFJiRFpYOG5USEgzaVZ4YWQ5OXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiblBFU0FqRjJ3WFMyajJHZnBlUEMzT2lXK2ZDaGpTVDJnQnZZSXdSNUhTUHQ2QmxjcUZGUDFOUit0NzFKeUxMY28zaUl0VlVBNGtUMUJmYnlxWisrT3c9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjZjZmFlZTcwNGMxOTE1OGM2NjE1ZWM5OWViZjEzMjZmYzIwZTljNWMwYWY1ZmQzZGI3Y2FjZDdiM2Q4Y2IxMmQifQ%3D%3D; expires=Wed, 05-Oct-2016 10:53:50 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
< Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjJ5MTMwYXBpVDlqRTZ6U2NmNjBWb3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTm10QklTZTAydURkeU1kSm9Eam1UaGg1RlpvQWpncTBJTmRSd2poT01ORVRUa2l3MzNSSjJZTStPMWpGTVdYQ0JFRkt3M2ZUd3NRYVNTS3JLQkpLckE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjM5MmQ2YzEzNDYwM2M5YTc1MzI0ODZmMjBiYWZiNmYyM2Q4NzE0ZTEyOWE3NWUzZjRjMGIxMGFjMGVjZDgzNGIifQ%3D%3D; expires=Wed, 05-Oct-2016 10:53:50 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt">http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt</a>.
    </body>
* Closing connection 0
```

I find this really weird since if i use the lib requests from python 3.x:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1'}
req = requests.get('http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt', headers=headers)
print(req.text)
```

The response is all html from the page (this is what is supose to happen)

PS: I also used the `-L` flag with me `curl` so it can fallow redirects but it appears to end up in an infinite loop (`curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed`)

Why is this hapening? How to solve it?

Comment: @CamilStaps its: `curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed` along with multiple request and response headers, always the same... All the redirects from the loop it were in

Comment: Ok @CamilStaps, sec

Comment: In the Python code you are sending request to `http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt/` with trailing slash. Can that be the problem?

Comment: I already tried that with/without trailing slash, always with same result @CanVural. It works fine both ways in python, doens't work both ways using curl

Comment: Are you using any middleware on this route ?

Comment: I'm surprised to see `GET /pt/` in the curl headers when you're clearly not giving that trailing slash to curl. I cannot reproduce it, so it's a little difficult to debug here, sorry.

Comment: Yes for the language, but python requests doesn't have a problem, i guess the problem it's not that @shock_gone_wild

Comment: @CamilStaps, maybe i posted the curl headers from another curl request that i tried with trailing slash. Anyway with/without the result is the same ):

Comment: Are you using homestead or another server? If the latter, can you give the configuration? Or can you use wireshark or something like that to inspect how the two requests differ?

Comment: No homestaed, just artisan running on my LAN ip and port 8000. What's make it even weird is that with `requests` from python it works @CamilStaps

Comment: What about `requests` headers? The same as curl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting a cookie, and if that cookie is not present, you redirect the user with a `302 Found`, setting the cookie, to the same page. Specifically, you're checking for the `lang` cookie.

While Python requests (apparently) retains cookies when redirecting, curl doesn't do this by default. You can enable this by adding a cookie jar (a file where cookies are stored, `-c cookies.txt`) or setting the cookie manually (`-b lang=pt`).

For example:

```
$ curl -c cookies.txt -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0' -LI lemos.migueldvl.com/pt
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 09:18:45 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.26
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjJtcHVwUlwvbzJSUlhublVzSCtPVk5BPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImlKMEcrQkZDOGlLKzdoUStVUkNLaXBKaDl3N0RvVjBsY1NVMHMrK3hZRCs5ekRzVTg3ZTdUU1J1WHNMb3JUZ1FCWDNrRHRVOGFjdzhsY0JidzQzZEJRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJjMDhmZmY1OGQxMGY2YWI0YmJkY2M1MzlhYWMyNzNhOTA5YjMwNThjZjM5MTBhOGJhNjJjOWYzZWVlNDY0MGQ0In0%3D; expires=Wed, 05-Oct-2016 11:18:45 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ik96cjBZRUJnT0daV0lyU3RLYlk2Nmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidW5YMHYybUdMUktLSml0VVwvZWYxSFFTUkVKdEh3WHJQeFlNQmVYZG5aYXNhZyszQWNvY3loN09PWG1TNUJoY0RsMkRFZ0RYZE9XaXRvM1prNzNRKzRnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0OTVjYWRiOGIyOGNkZjM1YmFjMDczNTlmMzI4NTI5OWQ3NmZjNDhjZWFlZjQ2MDI3ZWIxZmMzZDVkNzI1ZGQ5In0%3D; expires=Wed, 05-Oct-2016 11:18:45 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Location: http://www.lemos.migueldvl.com/pt
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Fri, 04 Nov 2016 09:18:45 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 09:18:45 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.26
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: lang=pt; expires=Fri, 04-Nov-2016 09:18:46 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InRkMFwvaFpYUENiNjdIbVRPTStuR25BPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkZ1V2MwMk41aVYzMWVuNHBEb1JlRks0TCtmNzdxbTJIWGJYNWFldDZZXC93UlRZZmxyK3YxVmJqcDZsQm9pdFhmKzhQa0tUcXY3d0VTR2lQOW1rc1E0Zz09IiwibWFjIjoiZjcyZmI5MGJhNjk0N2Q5ZWQzM2Y4NGExNmIzNmJiNDY1NzI2NzhmMzMzZDJkMGZhMDFkMjRjMmI4M2JiNDMyMCJ9; expires=Wed, 05-Oct-2016 11:18:46 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjllMDl4cjZPbEpYcWF3VktLOFVCWWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTFkrMzBMR1ZuV01aMEplMUY5M001T1wvdzZJSWIxVTZDbmdhWVwvRWp4U3pyUUZraUZhZEp1TnR2QzI0TGY0XC9JakZZbnFuNDNtdzc1eTY4c0lYVEpwYkE9PSIsIm1hYyI6Ijc3ODg5NDcyOWIyOGEzYjc4ZmNmYzExYjAyNjY0ZTg1ZmM2YjFjM2FjZDNmODBlN2EyZjJlOTQ3MmZiM2M1YmMifQ%3D%3D; expires=Wed, 05-Oct-2016 11:18:46 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Location: http://www.lemos.migueldvl.com/pt
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Fri, 04 Nov 2016 09:18:45 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 09:18:46 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.26
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImppeXFEaFdWa3NXZlM3cG5iK3Jid0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT2pGcjFyTnN2ZStIU2tvcW53MmtKdUpudkFIOXNBT1FNQTdLbUlvbVZGbHplYnlzWHJiWW16RXVZRk0rc241Qjcwcm5RVGZTSmdOS0l0cWdDT0x1aUE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjM0YjhlYzIyMjcwOGUzNzZkOTU5YTk2Yzc4MGI5ODNlMTkyM2QxNjg2NGUzOGVmOTM0NWFlNTNjNWNlZDg3ODMifQ%3D%3D; expires=Wed, 05-Oct-2016 11:18:46 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ikt4cU5KUm9qNVhKZUxHb2dqOVlDNXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVlpZdkM5eTYzRFRGcGFaS2lOd3NsYzdsM1Y0MGt5QWlXS25WVzFJZ0k2TzlYZCtUdXZCQTVTNHpoOFNyMjdiV2pNNTFUQ1dMbGt6XC9YR1wvK2FLV2s1QT09IiwibWFjIjoiOTg2ZDMyNzMyODBiODZmMWM2ZTU2NWZlODc3ZmRkNjdiNTA4Yzg2ZDFmZTg0YmJhMzdjMTJiMDVjMWZjNTkwOCJ9; expires=Wed, 05-Oct-2016 11:18:46 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Fri, 04 Nov 2016 09:18:46 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```